# Understanding how strings and floats work

Tags: python

- Input
- - Get toy name
- - Get unit price
- - Get quantity ordered
- Process
- - Total price with tax is price times quantity
- - Total with tax is Total price times 7%
- Output
- - Print the toy name, and total price with tax.

```
    #Input (Receive info)
    charge_for_toy = float(input('\nEnter charge for toy: $'))

    #Process (Calculate info)
    SALES_TAX = .07
    sales_tax = (charge_for_toy + SALES_TAX)
    grand_total = charge_for_toy + sales_tax

    #Output (display info)
    print('\nCharge for toy = $', format(charge_for_toy, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Sales tax = $', format(sales_tax, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Grand total = $', format(grand_total, ',.2f'), sep='', end='\n\n')`
```

I attempted to put in the same line for Get toy name and quantity ordered as I did for

```
    charge_for_toy = float(inpuit('\nEnter charge for toy: $'))
```

I get told the string cannot float. I am a little lost on how to proceed.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: Also, `inpuit()` is certainly a typo.  If that were your real code, you would have gotten a different error.  It's very hard to help when you don't show us your actual code.

Comment: What's the actual question? are you looking for definition of strings and floats? Do you think that the name should be a float?

Comment: A float is a number.  When you enter the toy name, are you entering a number?

Answer (score 2):

> I attempted to put in the same line for Get toy name and quantity ordered as I did for

so you can't use the "same line," if you want letters in the name.  `input` defaults to a string so all you need is:

```py
#Input (Receive info)
name_for_toy = input('Enter toy name: ')
charge_for_toy = float(input('Enter charge for toy: $'))
toy_quantity = int(input('Enter toy quantity: '))   # int because can't have fraction of toy

#Process (Calculate info)
SALES_TAX = 0.07
subtotal = charge_for_toy * toy_quantity
sales_tax = subtotal * SALES_TAX                    # corrected, "+ SALES_TAX" incorrect here
grand_total = subtotal + sales_tax

#Output (display info)
print('Toy name =', name_for_toy)
print('Charge for toy = $', format(charge_for_toy, ',.2f'))
print('Sales tax = $', format(sales_tax, ',.2f'))
print('Grand total = $', format(grand_total, ',.2f'), end='\n\n')
```